# Json api create comments

Tags: comments, 8

I am using the *JSON API* module and I would like to create a comment. I was able to create nodes based on the documentation found [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/json-api/creating-new-resources-post), but I can't figure out how to create comments.

How can I add a comment using that module? I managed to do it through the default REST API module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows the same pattern in the **POST request with relationships** section of the docs you linked to.

- Your endpoint will be `/jsonapi/comment/$MY_COMMENT_TYPE`.
- Your data payload will need to contain both the `data` property (the  comment's properties) and `relationships` property (which will contain the comment's author & the entity reference commented on). To get a more concrete example of your data payload, perform a `GET /jsonapi/comment/$MY_COMMENT_TYPE` to see examples of existing comments.